# EXcel Average IF

Tags: excel

In Excel I would like to create a formula which would average values from COLUMN H depending on information in columns C. If, in column C, value is a specific location (e.g. Los Angeles) then it would Average column H

Comment: Have you tried the `averageifs()` function?  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910c45-1fc0-4389-a028-f7c5c3001690

Comment: ... or even the [AVERAGEIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-ff3c70f9-5afe-4d3e-87d4-717187f98c20) for a single criteria?

Comment: I've tried with what I know but I get error messages

Comment: =AVERAGEIF('Employee Data'!$H$2:$H$1290,"="&A52)

Comment: This is the formula came up with that I get an error on =AVERAGEIF('Employee Data'!$H$2:$H$1290,"="&A52)

Comment: It seems to me that the next logical step would be to edit your question to include what you have tried (working or not). Your formula should be no more complicated than `=AVERAGEIFS(H:H, C:C, "Los Angeles")` or  `=AVERAGEIF(C:C, "Los Angeles", H:H)`. (note the syntax column/criteria placement swap between the two).

Comment: Try it as `=AVERAGEIF('Employee Data'!$C:$C, A52, 'Employee Data'!$H:$H)` and don't worry about the full column references.

Answer (score 0):

Try it as,

```
=AVERAGEIF('Employee Data'!$C:$C, A52, 'Employee Data'!$H:$H)
```

Don't worry about the full column references. Only the intersection of the columns referenced with the [Worksheet.UsedRange property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840732.aspx) will be considered in the calculation. This is not true of all formulas but the modern [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34)/[COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED), [SUMIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169B8C99-C05C-4483-A712-1697A653039B)/[SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) and [AVERAGEIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-ff3c70f9-5afe-4d3e-87d4-717187f98c20)/[AVERAGEIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690) only calculate on the extents of the data available.